# Can't call main camera in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the x position of the main camera in visual studio but whenever I try *Camera.main* it throws the error " 'Camera' does not contain a definition for 'main'" any idea why this is? It recognizes the Camera class, but doesn't give any main method.

Comment: Doesn’t sound like your camera is tagged as such then

Comment: What do you mean? How would I tag it then?

Comment: It's certainly not VS studio's fault, also please provide your .cs file

Comment: @getALoadOfThisGuy `Camera.main` is actually something like `GetGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>()`. So @BugFinder suspects that it's because the missing tag 'MainCamera'

Comment: Are you **sure** you haven't another class in your project called `Camera`? It seems like you are not referring to Unity's `Camera` class. Try `UnityEngine.Camera.main` instead.

Comment: Sounds like a namespace conflict as Hellium says .. using the full namespace should work

Comment: I actually did have another class named Camera. I changed it and we're good to go. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Access the Camera you need to get the GameObject Camera. That means you need to make it as Menyus wrote with a tag or try to find it.

Here some options for you:

```
//Simple
[SerializeField] private Camera camera;

// Best Way to "Find" via Code but you need to set a Tag in the Editor
private Camera camera;
void Start()
{
    camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
}

//or also a possible way but you could get not the wanted Camera if you use more than one.
private Camera camera;
void Start()
{
    camera = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
}
```